# missing file with sage installation

Tags: linux, installation, sage

I just installed [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), and when I want to create a package for it, it says a file it missing:

`$ sage -p custom_package.spkg 
/usr/lib/sagemath/local/bin/sage: line 851: sage-logger: command not found`

I tried to take the file sage-logger on the internet and copy it in /usr/lib/sagemath/local/bin/, but then I got a "permission denied", whether I used sudo or not.

I installed sage via apt-get, as instructed on their website: 

`sudo -E apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo -E apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary`

Comment: Can you give a little more information on how you installed it?  Perhaps you need a more fully featured version to install these optional packages - there are some "stripped down" versions of Sage without such scripts floating around.

Comment: @kcrisman thanks, I updated the information. Where are the "stripped down" versions ?

Comment: The PPA is one such, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes.  Indeed, `sage-logger` is in the `build/bin` directory, so apparently it can't be found.  I believe this is because the PPA does not include all files - see [the BitBucket site](https://bitbucket.org/aims_za/sagemath-upstream-binary/src/d6f98a63d7a327149a60f418ecb93bf7fec51ff2/sagemath-upstream-binary/debian/?at=master) regarding this.

I *think* (though I cannot test this site easily) that if you pull the `sagemath-upstream-binary-full` you should get this.  Certainly [it is in that one](https://bitbucket.org/aims_za/sagemath-upstream-binary/src/d6f98a63d7a327149a60f418ecb93bf7fec51ff2/sagemath-upstream-binary/debian/sagemath-upstream-binary-full.install.in?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) and was [intentionally added](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.sage.release/3165) but I don't know whether that particular binary is updated regularly or not.  I saw at least Sage 7.5.1 with the `-full` available.